# heroku app failing in mobile only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, heroku

I have a little proof of concept app that I am getting together on heroku. It will run and behave as expected on the browser but will fail on mobile.

You can see it here:

http://thawing-cove-7208.herokuapp.com

Here is a log right after a failure on mobile:

```
2014-02-10T03:26:27.426650+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2014-02-10T03:26:27.426650+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-10T03:26:27.426650+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2014-02-10T03:26:27.426650+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-10T03:26:39.505641+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.236.114.85 at 2014-02-10 03:26:39 +0000
2014-02-10T03:26:39.511019+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
2014-02-10T03:26:39.511837+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-10T03:26:39.506849+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-02-10T03:27:20.743657+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-02-10T03:27:20.743657+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kNcR0PGYPqQoIvaA7k0E3KNo7uoXiWltLEv89bZ+KAQ=", "email"=>"ianseabock@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}
2014-02-10T03:27:20.742094+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 108.236.114.85 at 2014-02-10 03:27:20 +0000
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:170:in `handle_unverified_request'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:163:in `handle_unverified_request'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.744177+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2014-02-10T03:27:20.744524+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:177:in `verify_authenticity_token'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__215575419083342757__process_action__callbacks'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.746963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1485798236090211319__call__callbacks'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.747835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
2014-02-10T03:27:20.748351+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
2014-02-10T03:27:35.460430+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-02-10T03:27:35.464639+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-10T03:27:35.458712+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.236.114.85 at 2014-02-10 03:27:35 +0000
2014-02-10T03:27:35.463853+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
2014-02-10T03:38:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-02-10T03:39:02.843652+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1c4f85b by ianseabock@gmail.com
2014-02-10T03:39:02.867205+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by ianseabock@gmail.com
2014-02-10T03:39:03+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-02-10T03:39:03.583295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-02-10T03:39:06.075197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-02-10T03:39:06.613676+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUITUnicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT insteadUnicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-02-10T03:39:06.613676+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-10T03:39:06.613676+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-10T03:39:06.613676+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-02-10T03:39:06.815873+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-10T03:39:06.815671 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2014-02-10T03:39:06.916273+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-10T03:39:06.916123 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 exit 0> worker=1
2014-02-10T03:39:06.916530+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-10T03:39:06.916438 #2]  INFO -- : master complete
2014-02-10T03:39:06.916352+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-10T03:39:06.916270 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 11 exit 0> worker=2
2014-02-10T03:39:08.387080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-02-10T03:39:11.476410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: nope, just a little jQuery to fetch data from DOM elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

That seems to be your problem

Have you included `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your mobile layout anywhere?